# Out of office broken on Exchange 2007 server wide

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, email

We are running a 2007 Exchange server with the most recent rollout. We have a CAS server set up. Recently after routine maintenance we have had users complain that their Out of Office (OOF) is not turning off.

Both Outlook and OWA show that the OOF is turned off yet the automatic reply is being sent out. It seems to be limited to one database but could be more wide spread then that.

I have run a test useing https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com but that says that everything worked fine

How can this be fixed server side or is this something to fix client side?

Comment: Not saying it isn't the database just never seen that across a whole db before...if you move a mailbox to a different DB it suddenly works fine?  Are you sure there isn't a mailbox rule doing this instead?  if you do `outlook /cleanrules` (backup the user's rules first) does it still do it?

Comment: @TheCleaner We have had four different users have the same issue, they all started around the same time.  
  
We created a new mailbox to test and we can't turn the OOF on (It shows that it is on in Outlook and OWA but nothing happens when we send it an email)

The databases is probably just be a coincidence

Comment: What routine maintenance changes/updates were made?  Are the virtual directories correct for Exchange still?  You may try debugging: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831053 and see if the logs for OOF show you the issue as well.

Comment: OOO heavily relies on the Autodiscover service as well, is that functioning properly?

Comment: @DanBig I use the "Test E-mail AutoConfiguration..." and it runs fine. It gives me an OOF URL and I can open that URL with no errors (just a bunch of code)

Comment: @TheCleaner The maintenance was on unrelated systems but but required the servers to be turned off for a while. The Virtual Directories seem to be fine from what I can tell. There is stuff in the OOF logs but I will have to look up how to interpret it.